# Plotting hydrogen wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

This may sound a bit dumb but how do I plot the hydrogen wave functions? For example,  what is exactly being represented [in this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png)? Is it just the norm-squared of the wave function and is the z-axis sticking out of the page?

I'm not sure how to use any other application but I'm using the Mac grapher tool. Say I wanted to plot $\psi_{200}$. The combined radial and angular equation for this state is $$\psi_{200}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}a_0 ^\tfrac{3}{2}} \left(2-\frac{r}{a_0}\right)e^{-\tfrac{r}{2a_0}}$$ where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius. As I said, i'm pretty clueless. I'm not sure how to plot this in spherical coordinates so I just converted $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Basically, I plotted $$z=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}a_0 ^\tfrac{3}{2}} \left(2-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{a_0}\right)e^{-\tfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{2a_0}} $$When I do plot this, I get a flat plane with a sort of half-sphere in the centre, which is not what the image I linked above shows. I also tried graphing $\psi^2$ but I still did not get it. I feel like i'm missing something big.

Answer (score 2):

The plots you see in the Wiki images, are, as their title suggests, *probability density plots* ($\psi^2$, for Real $\psi$). Light shaded areas represent high probability areas, darker areas lower probability density.

Furthermore, they've been *sliced*, e.g. with an $x,y$-plane. For radially symmetric functions like $\psi_{2,0,0}$ (aka the $2s$ orbital) the specific slicing plane doesn't even matter: the $\psi^2$ value is the same in all directions as it only depends on $r$.

There's little to be gained from these plots for radially symmetric wave functions with regards to the simpler radial distribution plots like [these](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png).

If you really do want to plot radially non-symmetric probability density functions (e.g. for $2p$, 3$d$ or $4f$ orbitals) you'll need to find a tool to generate *contour plots*. I imagine advanced functions of Mathlab allow to do that.

---

Here's a *contour plot* of $\psi^2_{200}$ for $z=0$ (the $x,y$-plane):

[image: Hydrogen 2s]

The white areas are those of high probability density. The plot clearly shows the 'shell-like' structure of the hydrogen $2s$ orbital.

The plot was obtained by means of Wolfram alpha, by plotting the square of:

$$\psi=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}a_0 ^\tfrac{3}{2}} \left(2-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{a_0}\right)e^{-\tfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2a_0}}$$

For $a_0=1$.

Here's a excellent resource for visualised wave functions: [the Orbitron](http://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/)

Comment: Alright, so I got $\psi^2 = \frac{r^2}{2a^3}(1-\frac{r}{2a})^2 e^-\frac{r}{a}$. Do I just let $z=\psi^2$ and $r^2=x^2 + y^2 + z^2$?

Comment: @AyumuKasugano: surely you can see you can't equate $z^2$ in two different ways? You should  set $z=0$ and the vertical axis of your plot to $\psi^2$. That would give you a *slice* in the $x,y$-plane...

Comment: The Matlab function you are thinking of is called `isosurface`

Comment: I'll have a shot at plotting this myself, using Wolframalpha, tomorrow. Bed time now.

Comment: Contour plot added.

Comment: Isn't this probability density $4\pi r^2 \psi ^2$? Why do we only graph $\psi ^2$?

Comment: $4\pi r^2\psi^2$ is for the *radial probability distribution*. Your $\psi$ has been fully normalised, so $\psi^2(x,y,z)$ is indeed the probability density distribution in space. But to find the *actual probability* of finding the electron in some volume element $V$ you still need to integrate: $P=\int_V \psi^2dV$ and that does involve the factor $4\pi  r^2$.

Comment: We don't only graph $\psi^2$ but the probability densities are more important than the wave values, in many instances. See  http://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/AOs/3s/e-density.html (play around with it!)

Comment: See https://www.shodor.org/refdesk/Resources/Activities/VisHydrogen/ for a clear discussion of how to plot radial hydrogen wave functions in two dimensions, and see https://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/ for a variety of plots (some animated to show the effects of mutual approach) of many orbitals of hydrogen and some other atoms.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac there still is [Atom in a Box](http://daugerresearch.com/orbitals/index.shtml). It can display hydrogen wave functions in different ways. I found the view mode with "phase as color" very helpful for my understanding. The wave functions are displayed in 3D and animated in time. One can also display superpositions of different eigenfunctions (for example the hybridizations from chemistry).